# How to recover from a shutdown AWS SES account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

My Amazon SES Reputation Dashboard shows my **Account status** as *shutdown*.

Also, it shows my **Bounce rate** and **Complaint rate**:

> HEALTHY Bounce Rate 1.99%
>
> SHUTDOWN for 244,176 more emails. Complaint Rate 1.04%

My AWS SES credentials were publicly exposed and someone sent thousands of emails from my account. After that, AWS paused my account from sending emails and told me to rotate the access and secret keys, and to delete the IAM User, and I did that.

For more details, here's a screenshot of the AWS SES dashboard:

[image: AWS SES dashboard]

Unfortunately, I am still not able to send emails. Can anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an Amazon customer support issue and has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon are quite protective of their reputation for email, quite rightly. If you are using the shared SMTP service, you are using one of Amazon's shared IP Addresses, and if an IP Address is added to a SMTP Blacklists its an endless battle to get them off. That affects more than just you.

According to the Amazon [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/e-faq.html):

> After you make changes that you believe will resolve the issue, send an email to ses-review@amazon.com from the email address associated with your AWS account. In your message, provide detailed information about the steps you've taken to resolve the issue, and describe how these steps prevent the issue from happening again in the future.

They want to know that you have taken enough steps to rectify the situation and prevent it from happening again.

Another option is to use an SES [Dedicated IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dedicated-ips.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console), this allows for more tolerance, and you manage your own reputation.

Comment: I already sent an email to aws 2 days ago. But still didn't receive any response from them.

Comment: If you don't have a support arrangement with AWS, their response times are lower. I know when I made a request to increase the limits on my SES send rate, it took about a week for them to respond.

Comment: If i resolve the above issue after review period, Will aws activate my account to send the emails again?

Comment: If they are happy that you have reasonable steps to stop it happening again, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a new account for email sending. Start slow and protect your API keys :)